# How to fix 'found more than one class "xts" in cache' message in R?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

In a custom package I'm using the class `xts` which leads to a namespace conflict when loading the `quantmod` package. Apparently, one can solve the problem by specifically importing functions from the `quantmod` package to the custom package. However, I don't want to do that as `quantmod` in my case is loaded as a dependency of `highcharter`.

Is there a way to resolve the conflict so that the message `Found more than one class "xts" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'custom_package' Also definded by 'quantmod'` doesn't show every time I'm working with an `xts` object?

Comment: Do you mean that you have created your own class called `xts`? If so, you should try to rename your class to something else. xts is a very popular time series data structure and any hacks you might try to avoid the namespace collision will eventually break if your end user needs to import any packages that depend on xts or if any of your other third party packages start depending on xts in their hierarchy.

Comment: @Jared Marks No, we just registered the S3 Class xts of the xts package with setOldClass() in order to write methods for a S4 function (of a different package)